# Meteor.js mplement a singleton confirm box

Tags: javascript, templates, meteor, meteor-blaze

I try to create a reusable confirm box, but i'm unsure how to implement this the meteor way.

I have a template for the confirm box. The text and button value should be dynamic.

```
<template name="confirm">
  {{#if show}}
    {{text}}
    <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
    <button class="confirm">{{action}}</button>
  {{/if}}
 </template>
```

And i have a user template with an delete button.

```
<template name="user">
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <button class="delete">delete user</button>
</template>
```

In the app template i display a list of users and render the confirm template.

```
<template app="app">
  {{#each user}}
    {{> user}}
  {{/each}}

  {{> confirm}}
</tempalte>
```

Now when i click the delete button of a user item i want to display the confirm box.

```
Template.confirm.helpers({
  text: function(){
    return Session.get('confirmText');
  },
  action: function(){
    return Session.get('confirmAction');
  },
  show: function(){
    return Session.get('showConfirm');
  },
});

Template.user.events({
  'click .delete': function(){
     Session.set('confirmAction', 'delete');
     Session.set('confirmText', 'Are you sure?');
     Session.set('showConfirm', true);
  }
});
```

My confirm box displays as it should but how can i trigger the user deletion from the confirm box?

Am i even on the right track? I tried to render a confirm template inside of every user template but there should only be one active confirm box at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can certainly make it work using this pattern. The only addition you need to make is to set the user id you intend to delete in the Session, so it is accessible to your deletion method:

```
Template.user.events({
  'click .delete': function(){
    Session.set('confirmAction', 'delete');
    Session.set('confirmText', 'Are you sure?');
    Session.set('showConfirm', true);
    /* addition - this._id refers to the id of the user in this template instance */
    Session.set('userToDelete', this._id); 
  }
});
```

And then:

```
Template.confirm.events({
  "click button.confirm": function(){
    Meteor.call(
      "deleteUser",
      Session.get("userToDelete"),
      function(error, result){
        Session.set("userToDelete", null);
      }
    );
  }
});
```

However a more flexible and extensible pattern would be to get and set the user you are confirming deletion of internal to the user template, using a `ReactiveVar` or `ReactiveDict` attached to the template instance. That way you are not loading up the global Session object with keys that really only involve one piece of behavior. And you could reuse your `confirm` template in other, unrelated contexts.

UPDATE

Here is a way to reuse a confirm button across contexts with a private reactive-var. To see if another confirmation box is open you can first check a Session property.

```
Session.setDefault("confirming", false);
```

The `text` and `action` properties in the `confirm` template are set from its user parent:

```
<template app="app">
  {{#each user}}
    {{> user}}
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="user">
  <h1>{{name}}</h1>
  <button class="delete">delete user</button>
  {{#if show}}
    {{> confirm text=text action=action}}
  {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="confirm">
  {{text}}
  <button class="cancel">cancel</button>
  <button class="confirm">{{action}}</button>
</template>
```

And we set the helpers and events for it in the user parent as well:

```
Template.user.created = function(){
  this.show = new ReactiveVar(false);
}

Template.user.helpers({
  name: function(){
    return this.name;
  },
  show: function(){
    return Template.instance().show.get();
  },
  text: function(){
    return "Are you sure?";
  },
  action: function(){
    return "delete user";
  }
});

Template.user.events({
  "click button.delete": function(event, template){
    if (Session.get("confirming")){
      console.log("You are already confirming another deletion.");
      return;
    }
    Session.set("confirming", true);
    template.show.set(true);
  },
  "click button.confirm": function(event, template){
    Meteor.call(
      "deleteUser",
      this._id,
      function(error, result){
        template.show.set(false);
        Session.set("confirming", false);
      }
    )
  }
});
```

Now you can give the `confirm` template a different context somewhere else based on its parent.

Comment: wouldn't be both solutions tied to user deletion? what if i want to delete other tings, or when i use the confirm box to confirm an order.  I Already tried it with ReactiveVar but how can i close the other boxes if i open a new one?

Comment: I edited my answer to show a possible solution - let me know if this helps.

Comment: This helped me a lot! Thank you Jeremy. I was using ReactiveVar the wrong way all the time. this changes a lot